# Rotating a String Using Lambda

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

So I encountered this question today, but since we are given the answer I tried rotating it using lambda, I doubt my approach which was using the reverse string using lambda to rotate it but would appreciate feedback on how I can approach this. code below

We are given two strings, A and B.

A shift on A consists of taking string A and moving the leftmost character to the rightmost position. For example, if A = 'abcde', then it will be 'bcdea' after one shift on A. Return True if and only if A can become B after some number of shifts on A.

Example 1:
Input: `A = 'abcde'`, `B = 'cdeab'`
Output: `true`

Example 2:
Input: `A = 'abcde'`, `B = 'abced'`
Output: `false`

My Interface:

```
public interface MyString {

    String myStringFunction(String str, String str1);

}
```

Class

```
public class RotateString {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static String onRotateString(MyString rotateString, String A, String B) {


        return rotateString.myStringFunction(A, B);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        MyString rotate = (A,B)->{

            String results ="";

            for(int i =0;i <A.length() ; ++i)

            for(int j = 0; j < B.length() ; ++j)

                 if (A.charAt((i+j) % A.length()) != B.charAt(i))

                results += A.charAt((i+j) % A.length()) != B.charAt(i);

            return results;

        };

        System.out.println(onRotateString(rotate,"abcde","abcde"));

    }

}
```

just practicing. 
OutPut: `truetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetruetrue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It produces far more logical output if you just replace this weird line:

```
results += A.charAt((i+j) % A.length()) != B.charAt(i);
```

with

```
results += A.charAt((i + j) % A.length());
```

(I think you copy-pasted too much from the line above it, you don't need to the the `!=` check in the line that appends to `results`)

Comment: Thanks very much, so I am trying :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the nature of your rotation algorithm, here's another strategy:

```
String a = "abcde";
String b = "cdeab";

boolean result = a.length() == b.length() && (a + a).contains(b);
```

The result will be true if both strings have the same length, and if `b` is a substring of `a + a`:

```
abcdeabcde
  |||||
  cdeab
```